# Server-side GWT events; alternative to Vaadin

Tags: gwt, web-frameworks, vaadin, server-side

I'm wondering is there a similar framework like Vaadin built on top of GWT which wraps the original GWT components but with server-side only event handling? (I know that Vaadin is built on top of GWT. I'm looking for an alternative solution.)

Vaadin is nice because of it's precompiled nature. I found compile times with GWT horrific the last time i've worked with it. Also it's a bit easier to maintain security if event handling code runs on the server. It would be nice if the standard GWT could be used in a similar way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is another like vaadin. and vaadin is already server-side..

see this http://vaadin.com/learn for more info

Comment: Looks like this is the best answer for the problem. Echo could be an alternative but it's nowhere as actively developed as Vaadin. Also Vaadin has a better community behind and it can be also better integrated with portlet standards which may will be a requirement for us. GWTEventService is not a direct alternative but it could be used as a tool to build something similar as Vaadin on top of GWT. So i stick with Vaadin for now.

Answer (score 5):

Have you seen this? - http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/

Comment: Thanks, looks interesting. I'll check this out later.

Answer (score 3):

For server-side alternative, you might take at a look at [ZK](http://zkoss.org) too.

Notice that its client side is based on jQuery, not GWT. However, you won't notice it at all since they both are server-side solutions and using pure Java.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers that you normally deal with are in server-side Java code. Consider this:

```
    final Button testButton = new Button("Test Button");
    testButton.addListener(new Button.ClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
        {
            mainWindow.showNotification("I am server-side code!");
        }
    });
```

As you said, you need to compile GWT code only when adding a custom component to your code. Vaadin's built in components are already compiled and put in the jar file. Although sometimes your IDE might detect your project as a GWT project and try to compile the widgetsets every time you change the code, when you might want to ask it to ignore.

If you look for alternatives to Vaadin you might have a look at [Echo2](http://echo.nextapp.com/site/echo2).

Comment: I know how Vaadin server side event handling works. I'm looking for an alternative to Vaadin itself.
I'll check out Echo2, thank you for suggesting.